# Open the datepicker calendar without showing the edittextbox in xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, datepicker, calendar, xamarin.forms

I am using `DatePicker` control of `Xamarin.Forms` in my app.I have a button and I want to open a popup in which I want to show the calendar of `DatePicker`. But currently when I open the popup, the `edittexbox` shows with current date and when I tap on the textbox then calendar opens. But I don't want the edit texbox.  I just want to show the calendar when user tap on the button.
Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make the DatePicker control hidden by setting `IsVisible=false`.  Then you can trigger it programmatically by calling the `Focus()` method from elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason, Its working perfectly. But I have one issue with that. I am not able to handle the Cancel button of DatePicker in android. I am trying to create a custom renderer for datepicker. But don't know how to access the cancel event in it. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: As of today, this no longer works on Android. You have to actually tap on the control to make it open. Focusing doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Check this :

```
        DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker
        {
            Format = "D",
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            IsVisible =false,
            IsEnabled = false
        };

        Button button = new Button
        {
            Text = "Date",
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
        };
        button.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            IsEnabled = true;
            datePicker.Focus();
            button.Text = datePicker.Date.ToString();
        };
```

Refer : 
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker/

Answer (score 2):

A slightly improved answer on Jason's answer. Setting `IsVisible` on the DatePicker to false and then setting it to `Focus()` does work, however, you may find that when you click Cancel, focus remains on the DatePicker. If the DatePicker already has focus, it will not show the date picker dialog again. Here is code which will always work regardless of how the user interacts with the dialog:

```
        DatePickerTapRecogniser.Tapped += (object sender,
                                           EventArgs e) => {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
                if (DatePickerComponent.IsFocused) {
                    DatePickerComponent.Unfocus ();
                }
                DatePickerComponent.Focus ();
            });
        };
```